# Switching current GL_COLOR_ATTACMENT in FBO

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Then we create buffer object we can specify many colour attachments from 0 to N

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, some_buffer);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D,some_texture_0, 0);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_TEXTURE_2D,some_texture_1, 0);
```

But then we draw to buffer, **how to control which colour attachment we use in FBO?** (default is 0), or multiple colour attachments works different way?

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, some_buffer);
//draw something
//switch to colour_attachment1
//draw something
//switch back to colour_attacment0
```

Comment: Your question is tagged oddly. Are you asking about desktop OpenGL or OpenGL ES? Because the answer will be different. Also, are you trying to draw to both in the same fragment shader or just one at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_TEXTURE_2D,some_texture_1, 0);
```

This line is not allowed in OpenGL ES 2.0. At least, not [without](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/NV/GL_NV_draw_buffers.txt) [extensions](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/NV/GL_NV_fbo_color_attachments.txt). OpenGL ES simply does not support having multiple color buffers. There is only `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0`; nothing more than that.

So if you want to draw to one buffer then another, you need to bind a new FBO to do so.